# Has Matt Murdock ever tried to pass as sighted?

Tags: marvel, comics, daredevil

It seems that Matt Murdock's abilities would allow him to convince most people he had normal vision. Particularly if he wore sunglasses, in case something about his nonexistent eyesight might convey strange body language.

So it seems to me that he has made a choice to present himself as blind - but has that always been the case?

Note: I specifically mean when Murdock is not dressed as Daredevil, just being himself.

Comment: Does it count when he's pretending to be his (fictional) non-blind twin brother, Mike?  Because that was a thing.

Comment: Daredevil #25 - 1967

Comment: Also in the most recent TV series, he pretends to be sighted; *Cut Man*

Comment: In some of the less extreme portrayals of his powers, he does have some limitations due to being blind, such as not being able to read print (at least not without touching it) or perceive small features of things very far away, or colors. In these portrayals, he couldn't really pretend to be able to see. He wouldn't look like a sighted person, he'd look like a blind man with superpowers, which presumably he wouldn't want, with the whole secret identity thing.

Comment: Of course, in the more extreme portrayals he can probably smell colors, soooooo.

Comment: He could cover those things by, for instance, claiming to be extremely colour blind and dyslexic. But then I guess he'd have to constantly be explaining himself, which would become tiresome, whereas appearing obviously blind is a much more instant cue that people will understand without explanation. It's also a better default alibi for his secret identity, since most people's expectations would be that a blind man couldn't be DareDevil, whereas a colour blind/dyslexic person could.

Answer (score 8):

In [Daredevil Vol.1 #25](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Daredevil_Vol_1_25), Matt pretends to be his own (fictitious) twin brother, *Mike* Murdock. Mike is apparently sighted and makes repeated allusions to the prettiness of his associate, Karen.

[image]

In the most recent TV series, Matt pretends to be sighted over the course of several episodes including *[Blindsided](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6741930/)*

Comment: https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/08/13/marvel-daredevil-mike-murdock/

Comment: Fights like that are why I stopped watching the TV series.  If DD had this much trouble dispatching three guys in the comics he'd have been dead a dozen times over.

Comment: @KyleJones - Fighting more than one person at once is [very difficult](https://www.quora.com/How-can-one-person-fight-more-than-3-people-at-the-same-time-and-win). Daredevil's only powers are superhuman senses, not strength or speed or durability. The fact that he can take on three opponents at once is actually extremely impressive, and that he has difficulty adds to the realism and self-consistency of his described power set.

Comment: @Adamant I saw no sign that DD was using his radar sense to detect approaches from behind.  No acrobatic ability either.  No bouncing thing soff walls as a force multiplier.  Just did not seem anything like Daredevil to me.

Comment: Back around 1990 or thereabouts, during Ann Nocenti's run as the regular writer of the "Daredevil" comic books, there was a time when Matt Murdock, a disbarred attorney, was trying to make a living as a prizefighter. A manager told him he'd need a special gimmick to stand out from the common herd of ambitious boxers, and Matt said brightly: "What if I fight blindfolded?" ;-> So for a few issues there, he was using a different name (I forget what) and *claiming* to be a trained boxer with normal vision who deliberately handicapped himself in the ring to make the fights more challenging!